# Constructor not setting values? Get method not working

Tags: java

this is an edit of my previous question since the each of the suggestions failed to fix the main issue. In my program, for some reason the values of monthName, year, and day are disappearing during the program. The output of this Test program is null,0,0. By the way, LongDate is inherited from the Date class which is not java.util.Date but rather it is a class that I created, and editDay and editYear are methods listed in the Date class.

Thanks so much. Any tips appreciated.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates an array of type Date filled with two LongDate objects

    Date [] collectionOfDates = { new LongDate("February",2,1996), new LongDate("February",13,1999) };

    // loops through the array and displays output of getDate() for each object

    for( int i = 0; i < collectionOfDates.length; i++ ) {

        System.out.println( collectionOfDates[i].getDate() );

    }

}

}
```

Here is the LongDate class:

```
public class LongDate extends Date {

private String monthName;
private int day;
private int year;

public LongDate(String m, int d, int y) {       

    super.editDay(d);
    super.editYear(y);
    editMonth(m);

}

public void setDate(String m, int d, int y) {

    monthName = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;

}


public String getDate() {

    StringBuilder fullDate = new StringBuilder();
    fullDate.append(monthName);
    fullDate.append(" ");
    fullDate.append(day);
    fullDate.append(", ");
    fullDate.append(year);

    return fullDate.toString();
}

public String getShortDate() {

    int month = 0;

    if (monthName.equals("January")) {
        month = 1;
    } else if (monthName.equals("February")) {
        month = 2;
    } else if (monthName.equals("March")) {
        month = 3;
    } else if (monthName.equals("April")) {
        month = 4;
    } else if (monthName.equals("May")) {
        month = 5;
    } else if (monthName.equals("June")) {
        month = 6;
    } else if (monthName.equals("July")) {
        month = 7;
    } else if (monthName.equals("August")) {
        month = 8;
    } else if (monthName.equals("September")) {
        month = 9;
    } else if (monthName.equals("October")) {
        month = 10;
    } else if (monthName.equals("November")) {
        month = 11;
    } else if (monthName.equals("December")) {
        month = 12;
    }

    StringBuilder shortDate = new StringBuilder();
    shortDate.append(month);
    shortDate.append("/");
    shortDate.append(day);
    shortDate.append("/");
    shortDate.append(year);

    return shortDate.toString();
}

protected String editMonth(String m) {

    // asks person to try again if month is not capitalized and spelled properly
    if (!m.equals("January") && !m.equals("February") && !m.equals("March") && !m.equals("April") && !m.equals("May") && !m.equals("June") && !m.equals("July") && !m.equals("August") && !m.equals("September") && !m.equals("October") && !m.equals("November") && !m.equals("December")) {
        m = Input.getString( "Invalid month. Please type the month again." );
        return m;       
    } else
        return m;
}
}
```